# Is there a performance difference between a squared function and directly calling powi(2) in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Rust, you can write `(x * x)` as `x.powi(2)`.

Is there any reason for/against wrapping `(x * x)` *(besides readability and personal preference)* into a function/macro in Rust, or is this equivalent to using `x.powi(2)`?

*(Where the constant `2`in `x.powi(2)` is folded and converted into `x * x`)*

Comment: Your right, I meant an objective, measurable reason and should have said so. Re-worded the question.

Comment: By changing your question, you've [invalidated an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38801702/155423). Although it's usually frowned upon to do so, there [appears to be precedent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311297/155423) that allows these types  of edits for off-topic questions. Hopefully creating that answer didn't take up a lot of the answerer's time.

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is about (1) `x.powi(2)` vs. `x * x` or (2) `x.powi(2)` vs. `squared(x)`. I.e., is this about inlining of user-defined functions or is it about rustc "knowing" to expand `x.powi(2)` where that expansion would be appropriate?

Comment: @trentcl, Im porting somce code from another language that uses `squared(x)`, my question is asking for any objective reasons to use or not use this convention. As it turns out the answer is: "There are no differences. So, write code which is most readable".

Comment: @ideasman42 The answer you accepted does not address function call overhead, but only shows that `x * x` is equivalent to `x.powi(2)`. `squared(x)` is not the same thing as either of those. Do you care about that?

Comment: @trentcl, yes, though this is an example of a function that could be set to inline (or use a macro).

Comment: @ideasman42 In that case, I suggest deleting the part about defining a `squared` function, since it was irrelevant to the answer you wanted

Comment: Thanks. Not a downvoter btw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, with the current Rust compiler they are equivalent, generating exactly the same result.

You can check out the assembly code generated for both variants via the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f9a785e45cddd2f52a42cab089db67f0&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]

pub fn square_mul(x:f64) -> f64 {
    x*x
}

pub fn square_pow(x:f64) -> f64 {
    x.powi(2)
}
```

Select a channel and release compilation mode, then press the `ASM` button in the top left corner. This is the output for Rust v1.10:

```
// square_mul:
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
retq

// square_pow:
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
retq
```

So Rust generates exactly the same code for both functions.

Comment: Your Rust Playground example makes it appear that much more "code" (if that assembly can be called code?) gets run for the `powi` case. Which goes against your point. Maybe this has changed since you posted the answer?

Comment: Did you switch to 'RELEASE' mode? When I do that, it doesn't just compile the same, the compiler actually only generates a single function to which both square_pow and square_mul symbols point to.

Answer (score 2):

If it reads better to you, this is already a reason to define it. You need a better reason not to, and I don't think there is one in this case: it isn't as if anyone reading the code will be puzzled what `squared` does.

Comment: Even in the case of readability, should the macro/function use `powi(2)` or not?